# How to use dataset in TensorFlow session for training

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I like to perform image classification on our own large image libary (millions of labeled images) with tensorflow. I´m new to stackoverflow, python and tensorflow and worked myself through a few tutorials (mnist etc.) and got to the point, where i was able to prepare a TensorFlow datset from a dictionary including the absolute path to the images and the according labels. However, i´m stuck at the point using the dataset in a TensorFlow session. Here is my (example) code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time
import mymodule # I build my module to read the images and labels
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes
from tensorflow.contrib.data import Iterator

beginTime = time.time()
batch_size = 100
learning_rate = 0.005
max_steps = 2
NUM_CLASSES = 25

def input_parser(img_path, label):
    one_hot = tf.one_hot(label, NUM_CLASSES)

    img_file = tf.read_file(img_path)
    img_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img_file, channels = 3)

    return img_decoded, one_hot

#Import Training data (returns the dicitonary with paths and labels)
train_dict = mymodule.getFileMap(labelList, imageList) 

#Import Test data
test_dict = mymodule.getFileMap(labelList, imageList)

#Get train data
train_file_list, train_label_list = get_file_label_list(train_dict)
train_images_tensor = ops.convert_to_tensor(train_file_list, dtype=dtypes.string)
train_labels_tensor = ops.convert_to_tensor(train_label_list, dtype=dtypes.int64)

#Get test data
test_file_list, test_label_list = get_file_label_list(test_dict)
test_images_tensor = ops.convert_to_tensor(test_file_list, dtype=dtypes.string)
test_labels_tensor = ops.convert_to_tensor(test_label_list, dtype=dtypes.int64)

#Create TensorFlow Datset object
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images_tensor, train_labels_tensor))
test_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_images_tensor, test_labels_tensor))

# Transform the datset so that it contains decoded images 
# and one-hot vector labels
train_data = train_data.map(input_parser)
test_data = test_data.map(input_parser)

# Batching --> How to do it right?
#train_data = train_data.batch(batch_size = 100)
#test_data = train_data.batch(batch_size = 100)

#Define input placeholders
image_size = 990*990*3
images_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, image_size])
labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[None])

# Define variables (these afe the values we want to optimize)
weigths = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([image_size, NUM_CLASSES]))
biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([NUM_CLASSES]))

# Define the classifier´s result
logits = tf.matmul(images_placeholder, weigths) + biases

# Define the loss function
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits, labels = labels_placeholder))

# Define the training operation
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

# Operation comparing prediciton with true label
correct_prediciton = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), labels_placeholder)

# Operation calculating the accuracy of our predicitons
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediciton, tf.float32))

#Create TensorFlow Iterator object
iterator = Iterator.from_structure(train_data.output_types,
                                   train_data.output_shapes)
next_element = iterator.get_next()

#Create two initialization ops to switch between the datasets
train_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(train_data)
test_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(test_data)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    #Initialize variables
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(train_init_op)
    for _ in range(10):
        try:
            elem = sess.run(next_element)
            print(elem)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print("End of training datset.")
            break
```

Following [this](https://kratzert.github.io/2017/06/15/example-of-tensorflows-new-input-pipeline.html) and [this](http://www.wolfib.com/Image-Recognition-Intro-Part-1/) tutorial i could not solve the problem of how to use the (image and label) dataset in a tensorflow session for training. I was able to print out the datset by iterating through it, but wasn´t able to use it for learning.

I don´t understand how to access the images and labels seperately after they have been merged in the train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images_tensor, train_labels_tensor)) operation, as requried by [the 2nd tutorial](http://www.wolfib.com/Image-Recognition-Intro-Part-1/). Also i don´t know how to implement batching correctly.

What i want to do in the session is basically this (from [the 2nd tutorial](http://www.wolfib.com/Image-Recognition-Intro-Part-1/)):

```
# Generate input data batch
indices = np.random.choice(data_sets['images_train'].shape[0], batch_size)
images_batch = data_sets['images_train'][indices]
labels_batch = data_sets['labels_train'][indices]

# Periodically print out the model's current accuracy
if i % 100 == 0:
  train_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={
    images_placeholder: images_batch, labels_placeholder: labels_batch})
  print('Step {:5d}: training accuracy {:g}'.format(i, train_accuracy))

# Perform a single training step
sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={images_placeholder: images_batch,
  labels_placeholder: labels_batch})

# After finishing the training, evaluate on the test set
test_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={
  images_placeholder: data_sets['images_test'],
  labels_placeholder: data_sets['labels_test']})
print('Test accuracy {:g}'.format(test_accuracy))

endTime = time.time()
print('Total time: {:5.2f}s'.format(endTime - beginTime))
```

If anyone can tell me, how to access images and labels in the dataset sepearately and use it for training, i would be really thankful. Also a tip where and how to do the batching would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `next_element` is a tuple of two tensors, matching the structure of your datasets: i.e. it is a tuple whose first element is an image, and second element is a label. To access the individual tensors, you can do the following:

```
next_element = iterator.get_next()
next_image = next_element[0]
next_label = next_element[1]

# Or, in a single line:
next_image, next_label = iterator.get_next()
```

To batch a `tf.data.Dataset`, you can use the [`Dataset.batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch) transformation. Your commented out code for this should simply work:

```
train_data = train_data.batch(batch_size = 100)
test_data = train_data.batch(batch_size = 100)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. With the iterator, i´m able to print out the image and label tensors seperately in a session, but if i feed it to "feed_dict" i get a TypeError, saying the feed can´t be a tensor...

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to feed the output of an iterator in a `feed_dict`. Instead of using `tf.placeholder()` to define the image and label input, reorder your code so that you use the tensors from `next_element` as the input to your model.